# My GCC compiler didn't identify the PlaySound function

Tags: c++, gcc5

I'm kinda confused when having the PlaySound function in my code. I did a double check the syntax and pretty sure I used the necessary library.

I'm using GCC version 5.1.0 and I had my WAV file in the same directory. Also, here is my code and the error in the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")

int main(){
 for(;;){
  PlaySound("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\Tick.WAV", NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME);
  Sleep(1000);
 }
return 0;
}
```

Error in console:
**C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Temp\ccokPOhD.o:test1.cpp:(.text+0x2e): unidentified reference to '_imp__PlaySoundA@12'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

If I'm doing anything wrong or missing something, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: There are just a few reason why you can get an undefined reference. Most of the time, there is a file that is not compiled, or the function implementation has a different signature from the declaration, or you don't link to a library. Without any other details (you don't show the implementation of `PlaySound`) The only solution I can offer is already in the dupe question. Let me know if you have other specific problem not answered there I could help you with.

Comment: I looks like the function was not declared as `extern "C"`. The docs say to just include `windows.h`. What happens if you remove the `#include <mmsystem.h>`?

Comment: This builds as-is in VS2022. Sorry, I don't have gcc installed on my Windows box. Nonetheless, it appears to be trying to link against a C++ mangled name. I'm not convinced that gcc supports `#pragma comment`, so you probably have to specify the library on the compile/link command line.

Comment: @jkb It still the same 'unidentified reference' line

Comment: @jkb: No, it does NOT appear to link against a C++ mangled name. That's a C/Windows mangled name. It's a common mistake for people coming from Linux, but Windows often mangles C names too. E.g. the `@12` comes from the 12 bytes needed for the arguments.

Comment: The problem is indeed GCC"s support for `#pragma comment (lib, )`. A `#pragma` is implementation-specific, and GCC chooses to ignore it. MSVC invented this particular `#pragma`, so it compiles there.

Comment: @Jin if GCC ignore pragma comment, you need to properly link to the library using either command line flags or your buildsystem configuration